# inequality in inner product

Tags: inequality, inner-products

I want to show that if $$(u-\hat u, v-\hat u)\leq 0$$ and also
$$(v-\hat v, u-\hat v)\leq 0$$
then
$$(\hat u-\hat v, u-v)\geq 0$$

Please help me. Maybe it is easy

Thanks

Comment: what does the hat stand for ?

Comment: u hat is the best approximation of u in the space k,that all u, u hat,v and v hat live in k. but I think it should solve without any consideration about what are these.

Comment: It's not true without the information about what $\hat u$ and $\hat v$ are. That is, if you allow $u$, $v$, $\hat u$, and $\hat v$ to be arbitrary vectors, then the implication fails, even in one dimension.  In $\mathbb R$, take $u=-2$, $v=2$, $\hat v=-1$ and $\hat u=1$.

Comment: are you sure about $$(v-\hat v, u-\hat v)\leq 0$$ ? If it were $$(v-\hat v, \hat v -u )\leq 0$$ I'd have the solution

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Euler identity

$$(u-\hat u, v-\hat u)- (v-\hat v, u-\hat v)+ (\hat u-\hat v, u-v)= 0.$$

(So I suppose you've made a typo)

Comment: I think it is not true, because it is not zero. even it can be zero, then we can not conclude the desired result,since the second term has mines sign.

Comment: @Hakhak Otherwise I can easily cook up a counterexample.

Comment: you are right, I found one of these.